# Unclear xamarin liscense

Tags: c#, android, licensing, xamarin

I am building an app using xamarin and some parts of the liscense are unclear to me.

> Xamarin Starter allows developers to build and publish simple apps, which contain no more than 64k of compiled user code (IL), and which do not call out to native third party libraries (i.e., developers may not P/Invoke into C/C++/Objective-C/Java. See the full product comparison chart.
>   Which do not call our to native third party libraries.

What exactly ( in details) does that mean? Can I use RestSharp? NUget? and other libraries like so ? Also why can't I use Java the app is in C# wrapping java (Xamarin) so I'm going to need to use some java somewhere.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2):

> [you cannot] create an app that has more than 64k of compiled code

Pretty self-explanatory.  This will include the IL of third-party assemblies that you use.

> [you cannot] P/Invoke into C/C++/Objective-C/Java

This doesn't mean you can't use any C# libraries (like RestSharp or something you get through Nuget).  It means you can't call a native method via a `DllImport` or the [`Export` attribute](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/binding_objc_libs/) for Objective-C (there are likely other restrictions, but I don't know of an exhaustive list).